# Interval Comparison With Dates/Hours on a Date Time Index (Checking if an hour is between 2 periods)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I know Im probably making this issue more complicated than it is but I'm essentially trying to determine of the hour of my datetime index is between a start time and an endtime. 
I tried:

```
rbe60['Hour'] = rbe60.index.hour
rbe60['result'] = rbe60['Hour'].between_time('3:00','23:00')
```

I've also tried:

```
rbe60['Hour'] = rbe60.index[20 <rbe60.index.hour <24]
```

But I keep getting
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

This is my df head

```
                       Open       H       L       C       O
DateTime                                                   
2013-12-30 14:30:00 -0.0756 -0.0729 -0.0756 -0.0737  2.8847
2013-12-30 15:30:00 -0.0735  -0.072 -0.0737 -0.0722  2.8870
2013-12-30 16:30:00 -0.0722 -0.0721 -0.0728 -0.0722  2.8930
2013-12-30 18:00:00 -0.0728 -0.0728 -0.0728 -0.0728  2.8826
2013-12-30 19:00:00 -0.0721 -0.0721 -0.0721 -0.0721  2.8872
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the attribute `hour`, the time is converted to an Int, and no longer a time, so instead of using
`rbe60['result'] = rbe60['Hour'].between_time('3:00','23:00')`
use
`rbe60['result'] = rbe60['Hour'].between(3, 23)`.

This could also be in a oneliner:

`rbe60['result'] = rbe60.index.hour.to_series().between(3, 23)`

I don't think you'll get (or want to get) more succinct than that.

You'll need to convert the index to a series by using [to_series()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html), as [between()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) is a Series-method.

Comment: is there a more succinct way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: is there a reason why this wont work        :rbe60['Hour'] = rbe60.index.hour.between(3,23)

Comment: I get this error:    rbe60['Hour'] = rbe60.index.hour.between(3,23)
AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'between'

Comment: I've tried to edit my answer to make it complete, does it fully answer your question now?

Comment: yes makes sense now - just one final question - i eventually want to add this as another condition in an np.logical. like this:   l_entry_off = np.logical_and(data['Slope'].shift(1) > entry_thresh, data['Slope'].shift(2) < entry_thresh)

Comment: will this work or can i not use it b/c it's a series and not an array?

Comment: In principle: yes. You haven't changed the index inplace, only for this result.

Comment: raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
Getting this error. I ran: dup = rbe60.index.get_duplicates() and it returned no duplicates

Comment: Ah, didn't see the same thing in your answer as mine. My bad.

Comment: anyone have an idea why im getting this duplicate axis error? Driving me crazy :)

Comment: This appears to be unrelated to this question. If you need help, feel free to ask a new question, and make sure to include the necessary sample data so people  can actually figure out where the problem is.